# error al imprimir los datos de un usuario logueado..!

Tags: php, mysqli

disculpen la molestia, pero tengo una gran duda, me sale un error al momento de mostrar los datos del usuario logueado, lo raro es que si me permite ingresar al momento que introduzco el usuario y contraseña.

Tengo un archivo **login.php**.

```
<?php
  require_once("clase/conexion.php");
  if(
    isset($_REQUEST["user"]) &&
    isset($_REQUEST["pass"])
    ){

    $query = $mysqli->query("
      SELECT * FROM admin 
        WHERE usuario = '".$_REQUEST["user"]."'AND 
              password = '".$_REQUEST["pass"]."'
      ");
    $con = $query->fetch_assoc();

    if(
      $_REQUEST["user"] == $con["usuario"] &&
      $_REQUEST["pass"] == $con["password"]
      ){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["user"] = $con["usuario"];
        $_SESSION["pass"] = $con["password"];

        header("Location: inicio.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

y una vista donde imprimo el nombre del usuario que se logeoo llamado **inicio.php**

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>
```

y me sale este error, diciendome que en la vista donde imprimo el nombre del usuario esta indefinida que seria **$_SESSION["usuario"]**.

Undefined index: usuario in C:\wamp64\www..

Comment: Fijate si el name que envías es el mismo declarado, y guarda lo que recibes en variables para que sea mas facil su manejo. Además no veo declarado `$_SESSION["usuario"];` Tu utilizas `$_SESSION["user"]`

Comment: Si muchas gracias! no me habia dado cuenta de ese pequeño detalle, nuevamente gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hombre tu mismo te muestras el error y la solución, quieres imprimir un arreglo de sesión con el indice `'usuario'` cuando estas declarando uno con el indice del arreglo del mismo como `'user'` en tu *login.php*

recuerda que al hacer:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $con["usuario"];
```

el indice del arreglo `$con` no pasa a ser el indice del arreglo `$_SESSION`

La solución es cambiar en:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>
```

Por:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["user"]; ?>
```

Comment: Si tienes razón nikomaster... muchas gracias por la ayuda!!